# Unload jQuery iFrame from Remote File

Tags: jquery, iframe, popup

I've got the following jQuery based iFrame popup and close working. When the function loadFrame is called with the correct arguments, my external content loads in a lightbox style popup. I can then unload the iframe by click on the icon_close.png image.

Is there a way that my loaded page (frame.php) can also somehow unload the iframe? because sometimes my popup will do a bit of processing and show a processing message but then when the processing on my frame.php is done, i want a way for the frame.php file to unload the iframe

```
function loadFrame(id, content){
     $('body').append('<div id="overlayFrame" style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;top:0px;left:0px;background: rgb(0, 0, 0); opacity: 0.8;"></div>');
    iframecontent.style.display="block";
    $('#iframecontent').html('<div id="iframe_'+id+'" style="position:relative;width:520px;"><div style="width:100%;text-align:right;"><img src="icon_close.png" border="0" onclick="unloadFrame(\''+id+'\')" data-tar="'+id+'" style="cursor: pointer;"></div><iframe src="frame.php?content=' + content + '&sid='+ id +'&cmd=1" name="frame" id="frame"></iframe></div>');
}

function unloadFrame(id){
    var iframeid = "#iframe_"+id;
    var overlayframe = "#overlayFrame";
    $(iframeid).remove();
    $(overlayframe).remove();
    iframecontent.style.display="none";
}
```